# Powershell DSC: Whats the recommendation if we want a process to be always running

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I want a process (exe) to be always running on machine, even after it reboots. I've setup powershell DSC and currently I had it as a WindowsProcess and its not launched after reboot. Can someone tell me whats the recommended resource to be used for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont really need DSC for that, just create a service with startup type of auto with the `sc` command. plenty of examples online.

```
sc create <servicename> binpath= "<pathtobinaryexecutable>" [option1] [option2] [optionN]
```

You can use [Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/serviceresource) to create services as well. Something like this should work:

```
configuration ServiceTest
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Node localhost
    {

        Service ServiceExample
        {
            Name        = "TermService"
            StartupType = "Manual"
            State       = "Running"
            Path        = "path\to\binary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I kind of need DSC for other purposes. I'm need to install something on my host machines of my kubernetes cluster. That's why I chose to use DSC and for the first time, it sets it up correctly and runs my exe. But I want to run this whenever a machine reboots as well. 
I can try to use this sc command in my WindowsProcess it self

Comment: check updated answer, if you still need dsc, you might as well use dsc to do that